# How to get a select order in Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a select box that changes the order of my MYSQL data.
the code i got so far returns a blank page and I can't figure out why..

```
$host = "IP";
$user = "USER";
$pwd = "PW";
$db_name = "DBNAME";

echo "<p>Order by: <select name='order' id='order' onChange='document.getElementById('order').submit();'><option value='DESC'>Newest</option><option value='ASC'>Oldest</option></select>";

if(!isset($_POST['order']) {
    $order = "DESC";
} else {
    $order = $_POST['order'];
}

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)or die("cannot connect"); 

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id ".$order." LIMIT 25") or die(mysqli_error($link));
//var_dump($sql);

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows['id']."'src='".$rows['foto']."' onclick='Bigscreen(this)'></img>";
}
```

Comment: Comment out all your code except for an echo. Then uncomment the lines one by one until the page goes blank - then fix the error in the line you just uncommented.

Comment: if your problem is solved by aneesh then accept his answer. It will be easier for others. what happens is people comes and think of answer, if answer is accepted then people will not waste time in thinking of answer

Answer (score 3):

Check for syntax error.
I can see already one in the script

```
if(!isset($_POST['order']) {
```

to

```
if(!isset($_POST['order'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your code and the blank page is because you can't see the error message.

Try putting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

At the top of your page.